# JavaScript Div Expanding

Tags: javascript, css, html

I hope someone can help me with this.
When my **HTML Textbox is clicked**, I would like a **Div to expand** in length using preferably only JavaScript. I attached a picture to show in more depth. Again, If anyone could help me - I'll be greatfull.

[image]

Comment: Iv tried using Jquery, But I am looking for a Simple JavaScript one

Comment: I'm looking for JavaScript, Not Jquery.

Comment: jQuery is a library written in JavaScript. We are not here to write your code for you. Show us the jQuery, try writing it in vanilla JavaScript yourself, and we will help you do that, not do it for you.

Comment: Here's a demonstration of resizing a `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/AZJzz/4/ Change the event to an `onfocus` on the `textarea` and edit to taste.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone too, Just asking for some help..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be sufficient, HTML:

```
<input type = "text" style = "width: 500px;" onfocus = "expand();" onblur = "collapse();">
<div id = "yourdiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#yourdiv {
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 162, 232);
    width: 500px;
    height: 0px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var t;
function expand() {
    var dv = document.getElementById("yourdiv");
    var duration = 500; //number of milliseconds for animation; 1000ms = 1s.
    var stepDur = Math.floor(duration / 200); //200px is our goal height here
    var curHeight = parseInt(dv.style.height.substr(0, dv.style.height.length - 2), 10); //current height of dv
    if(isNaN(curHeight)) {
     curHeight = 0;
    }
    clearTimeout(t); //make sure no other animation is happening
    function doAnim() {
        if(curHeight >= 200) {
             //we're done!
             return;
        }
        curHeight ++;
        dv.style.height = curHeight + "px";
        t = setTimeout(doAnim, stepDur);
    }
    doAnim();
}
function collapse() {
    var dv = document.getElementById("yourdiv");
    var duration = 500; //number of milliseconds for animation; 1000ms = 1s.
    var stepDur = Math.floor(duration / 200);
    var curHeight = parseInt(dv.style.height.substr(0, dv.style.height.length - 2), 10); //current height of dv
    clearTimeout(t); //make sure no other animation is happening
    function doAnim() {
        if(curHeight <= 0) {
             //we're done!
             return;
        }
        curHeight --;
        dv.style.height = curHeight + "px";
        t = setTimeout(doAnim, stepDur);
    }
    doAnim();
}
```

Demo: [little link](http://goo.gl/VHHPD).

I hope that helped!